# How to upload file through objective C?

Tags: objective-c, file-upload

I want to ask a question about the objective C on iPhone. I want to upload a file (actually I store all the data in a NSString) to a server. However, I have not idea of how to do, I have checked the website of the Apple Developer, and I know there are a function called `connection:didSendBodyData:totalBytesWritten:totalBytesExpectedToWrite:`, but it seems wrong. Can anyone help me and provide some sample code to me? Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found this is the answer
http://cocoadev.com/index.pl?HTTPFileUpload

Comment: Link is down. This one works: http://cocoadev.com/HTTPFileUpload. And maybe also interesting, this one: http://cocoadev.com/HTTPFileUploadSample